# MVC model does not update when data populated through jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using a kendo grid popup editor. I have a custom template (partial view) for edit. I have a drop down and on change event, I'm populating a `TextBox`. The problem is when I am sending the model to the controller, the `TextBox` value is null. It's not updating the model with the populated value. Any idea why?

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(w => w.AddressID)
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("AddressID")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetAddressType", "DataSource").Data("filterAddressTypes");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .CascadeFrom("CodeIDAddressType")
    .Events(e => e.Change("addressSubType"))
)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AddressLine1)
```

On an AJAX done function, I'm populating the value.

```
$("#AddressLine1").val(response.AddressLine1)
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateEvent([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, MyViewModel request, int ID)
    {
        try
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();
            var db = Event.New();
            db.EventID = ID;
            db.Name = request.Name;
            db.AddressID = request.AddressLine1, 
            db.Save();

            return Json(new[] { "" }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex);
            return Json(new DataSourceResult { Errors = ex });
        }
    }
```

I can see the new value in the text box but when submitted, it sends null to the controller. If I enter the value in the `AddressLine1` field instead of populating, it sends the entered value to the controller.

Comment: What type of model does the POST action accept?  The model accepted during POST has to have AddressLine1 as a direct property on it.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same view model in the page and controller. Values entered in the form are showing up in the controller. Only the populated values are null.

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler or some tool to check the values being posted?

Comment: Yeah, I checked using FireBug and it's sending empty string for AddressLine1 but I can see the value in the TextBox.

Comment: Try, just in case, `$("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.AddressLine1)").val(response.AddressLine1);` - using Html.IdFor as the means to guarantee the exact ID to use.